# Background image transition when switching classes

Tags: css, angularjs, css-transitions

I have a div with a background image. Using js I switch the class on that div to chaneg the background. I would like a smooth switch - not so abrupt as just switching. I am having difficulties with CSS transitions. Not sure I am using them right in this case. I can do changes with :hover but this doesn't seem to work.  As a side note I am using Angular ngClass to switch these classes and I see there is perhaps some use for ngAnimate...

```
.waiting {
  background-image: url("/images/waiting.png");
  -webkit-transition: opacity 10s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 10s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 10s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 10s ease-in-out;
}

.uploading {
  background-image: url("/images/uploading.png");
  -webkit-transition: opacity 10s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 10s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 10s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 10s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div{position:relative;}
div:after,
div:before{
    content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  opacity: 0;
  background-image: url("/images/waiting.png");
  -webkit-transition: opacity 10s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 10s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 10s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 10s ease-in-out;
}
div:before{background-image: url("/images/uploading.png");}
div.waiting:after{opacity:1;}
div.uploading:before{opacity: 1;}
```

Comment: Oh that's really nice and clever!  My actual problem is 3 images. (waiting, uploading, complete). Can you use this with 3 states?  My experiments got my almost there but not quite.

Comment: use two blocks
<div><div></div></div>
div>div{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 opacity:0;
 opacity: 0;
 background-image: url("/images/waiting.png");
 -webkit-transition: opacity 10s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity 10s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: opacity 10s ease-in-out;
 transition: opacity 10s ease-in-out
}
div.complite>div{opacity:1;}

Answer (score 0):

Like this? **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mUsX/1/)**

```
div {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
.waiting, .waiting > span {
    background-image: url("http://static3.fjcdn.com/thumbnails/comments/feels+man+_96209287ce84931447c2d1b56fd3ef29.jpg");
    -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 200ms linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 200ms linear;
    -ms-transition: opacity 200ms linear;
    transition: opacity 200ms linear;
    display:block;
}
.waiting > span {
    cursor:pointer;
    opacity:0;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-size:contain;
}
.waiting span:hover {
    opacity:1;
    background-image: url("http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m1wo3uPxfH1qzfo1i.png");
}
```

Comment: I am not using :hover so I don't know if it can work. Works with :hover fine. But when I just switch classes using JS no. It may be that I need to handle the aninmation using javscript (angular in my case)

Comment: Why would you use js in this case? `:hover` seems to be working fine right?

Comment: Because it's changed by JS. It's not a human interaction thing. It's an image that changes based on something that happens in code - in this case it's an image uploader.